# Instance member is not accessible in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

This is my first time to develop a react application.

I want to access the method from another js file. The IDE says that Instance member is not accessible. I imported/ exported the filenames so that it can be accessed.

On File 1, I imported the js file.

```
const Log = require("./Log");
```

and then access it by

```
await Log.createAuditLog(transaction, transactionSeq, dataQuery.rows, details);
```

it says on this line that Instance member is not accessible (createAuditLog)

This is the content of Log.js

```
class Log {
  constructor(logger, database) {
    this._logger = logger;
    this._database = database;
  }


  async createAuditLog(transaction, transactionSeq, dataQuery, details) {



    try {
      await this._database.simpleExecute(`INSERT INTO LOG (AUDIT_LOG_ID, ACTION, TRANSACTION_SEQUENCE, USER_ID, DATA_BEFORE, DATA_AFTER) VALUES (AUDIT_LOG_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, :OPERATION, :TRANSACTION, :USER_ID, utl_raw.cast_to_raw(:BEFORE), utl_raw.cast_to_raw(:AFTER))`, bindVars);
    } catch (err) {
      this._logger.error("Could not insert audit trail.", err);
      throw new TxnError(500, `Audit trail error. ${err.message}`);
    }

    this._logger.info("Created Audit trail.", {txnSeq: transactionSeq, operation: transaction});
  }
}

module.exports = AuditLog;
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: make createAuditLog as static method.
static async createAuditLog

Comment: You either need to instantiate an instance of the Log class, or as @CuongTranDuc said make the method static so it can be accessed without instantiating the class.